# Running Unix command using Java

Tags: java, unix, cygwin, processbuilder

I have been trying to show the output of a simple unix command in java(using cygwin). I have read that unlike cmd, unix shells does not provide terminal functionality, so I installed cygwin, yet I am still not able to execute this. Here is my code, I tried to print the output of a line from ps -ef.Currently, I am receiving "Failed to run 'ps -ef': No such file or directory"

```
try {
   Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\mintty.exe",  "ps -ef" });

    //process.waitFor();
    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

    System.out.println("A line from ps -ef command:\n");                  
    s = stdInput.readLine();
    System.out.println(s);             
    System.exit(0);
} catch (IOException e1) {
    System.out.println("exception happened");
    e1.printStackTrace();
    System.exit(-1);
}
```

Comment: "Not able to execute" is not a helpful problem description ... error messages, exceptions, what happens?

Comment: I usually find that wrapping the whole command into a script and running that is the best solution.

Comment: The latest(this one) version gave this: Failed to run 'ps -ef': No such file or directory

Comment: @Steve Smith I tried doing that too, no luck.

Comment: What happens if you run the script directly (from the same directory as your java app)?